# How to replace node xml in OmniXML?

Tags: xml, delphi

I have an xml document loaded by my Delphi program using OmniXML. How can I replace a specific node with a new one defined by xml string?

Or, in other words, how can I edit xml representation of a node and apply the changes?
Something like XMLNode.SetXML(NewXML:String):

```
XMLNode.SetXML('<Test><TestNode>This is a test</TestNode></Test>');
```

Comment: Great, thanks! The question is much clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a way to actually replace the existing XML for a node with new XML (especially if that XML has multiple level nodes).

I did figure out how to accomplish what you want to do, however.

- Create a new, temporary XML document for your new XML content
- Create a new node in the existing XML structure as a child of the parent node owning the node you want to replace.
- Copy the node(s) from the temporary XML document into the newly created child node.
- Delete the original node and replace it with the new child node you've created (using the parent node's `ReplaceNode`).

Here's a quick example console app that does just that, using the following XML to start with (saved in `test.xml` in a local folder on my machine). The XML file contains this content (I've omitted the XML processing instruction for brevity, but the code works with it as well):

```
<AddInList>
  <AddInItem>
    <Title>Original title</Title>
    <Description>Original description</Description>
  </AddInItem>
</AddInList>
```

The code:

```
program XMLReplaceNodeContent;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  OmniXML,
  OmniXMLUtils;

var
  XMLDoc: IXMLDocument;
  TempDoc: IXMLDocument;

  OldNode, NewNode, NodeToDelete: IXMLNode;

const
  XMLFile = 'e:\tempfiles\Test.xml';

  NewXML = '<AddInItem>' +
           '<Title>This is a test node</Title>' +
           '<Description>New description</Description>' +
           '</AddInItem>';

begin
  XMLDoc := CreateXMLDoc;
  // Turn off any formatting. We'll add it back later, if you want
  XMLDoc.PreserveWhiteSpace := False;
  XMLDoc.Load(XMLFile);

  TempDoc := CreateXMLDoc;
  TempDoc.PreserveWhiteSpace := False;
  TempDoc.LoadXML(NewXML);

  XMLDoc.SelectSingleNode('AddInList', OldNode);
  OldNode.SelectSingleNode('AddInItem', NodeToDelete);

  // Create replacement node(s) from new XML
  NewNode := XMLDoc.CreateElement('AddInItem');

  // Copy replacement nodes to new node of original XML
  CopyNode(TempDoc.DocumentElement, NewNode, True);

  // Replace the original node with the new node
  OldNode.ReplaceChild(NewNode, NodeToDelete);

  // To prevent formatting of XML, comment this line and
  // uncomment the next one
  XMLSaveToFile(XMLDoc, XMLFile, ofIndent);
  // XMLDoc.Save(XMLFile);

  Writeln('XML with replace node saved successfully');
  Readln;
end.
```

The final output in `Test.xml`:

```
<AddInList>
  <AddInItem>
    <Title>This is a test node</Title>
    <Description>New description</Description>
  </AddInItem>
</AddInList>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Comments are lost, e.g. `<!-- This is a comment -->` is replaced by `<#comment/>`, but I can deal with that.